# URL routing containing parameters

Tags: php, url-routing

I have been trying to create a route that accepts parameters to get a single user but I am struggling to understand what I am doing wrong, I am stuck.

Here are the routes:
The 1st one works without any issues:

```
<?php
$router->get('users', 'UsersController@index');
$router->get('users/about', 'UsersController@test');
$router->get('users/:id', 'UsersController@show');
```

Here is my Router Class, I am matching the urls and using preg_replace so I can get the id dynamically

```
<?php

namespace App\Core;

class Router
{
    /**
     * All registered routes.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $routes = [
        'GET' => [],
        'POST' => []
    ];

    /**
     * Load a user's routes file.
     *
     * @param string $file
     */
    public static function load($file)
    {
        $router = new static;

        require $file;

        return $router;
    }

    /**
     * Register a GET route.
     *
     * @param string $uri
     * @param string $controller
     */
    public function get($uri, $controller)
    {
        $this->routes['GET'][$uri] = $controller;
    }

    /**
     * Register a POST route.
     *
     * @param string $uri
     * @param string $controller
     */
    public function post($uri, $controller)
    {
        $this->routes['POST'][$uri] = $controller;
    }


    /**
     * Load the requested URI's associated controller method.
     *
     * @param string $uri
     * @param string $requestType
     */
    public function direct($uri, $requestType)
    {
        $matches = [];

        foreach ($this->routes[$requestType] as $regex => $controller) {

            $pattern = "@^" . preg_replace('/\\\:[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+/', '([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)', preg_quote($regex)) . "$@D";

            if ( preg_match($pattern, $uri, $matches ) ) {

                print_r($matches[0]);


                return $this->callAction(
                    ...explode('@', $this->routes[$requestType][$uri])
                );
            }
        }

        throw new Exception('No route defined for this URI.');
    }

    /**
     * Load and call the relevant controller action.
     *
     * @param string $controller
     * @param string $action
     */
    protected function callAction($controller, $action)
    {

        $controller = "App\\Controllers\\{$controller}";
        $controller = new $controller;

        if (! method_exists($controller, $action)) {
            throw new Exception(
                "{$controller} does not respond to the {$action} action."
            );
        }

        return $controller->$action();
    }
}
```

And in my users controller I simply have a function that gets the id and shows me the user based on $id

```
/**
 * Show selected user.
 */

public function show($id)

{
$id = array_slice(explode('/', rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')), -1)[0];

$user = App::get('database')->get('users', [
    'id' => $id
]);

return view('user', compact('user'));
}
```

If you guys need more infos I can add the whole code into a code-pen. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this section ( method `direct`)

```
explode('@', $this->routes[$requestType][$uri])
```

This should be

```
explode('@', $this->routes[$requestType][$regex])
```

Or simply (and preferred):

```
explode('@', $controller)
```

as the URI (for the 3rd one) is something like this:

```
users/10
users/20
```

And the actual key is: `users/:id` which is also the `$regex` value (obviously)

Code (For testing only):

```
$routes = [
    'GET' => [
        'users'=>'UsersController@index',
        'users/about'=>'UsersController@test',
        'users/:id'=>'UsersController@show'
    ],
    'POST' => []
];

$requestType = 'GET';

$uri = 'users/10';

foreach ($routes[$requestType] as $regex => $controller) {
    $pattern = "@^" . preg_replace('/\\\:[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+/', '([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)', preg_quote($regex)) . "$@D";
    
    if ( preg_match($pattern, $uri, $matches ) ) {
    
        print_r($matches[0]);
        echo "\n";
        print_r($routes[$requestType][$uri]);
        echo "\n";
        print_r($routes[$requestType][$regex]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
  #$matches[0]
  users/10
  #with $uri as the key - $routes[$requestType][$uri]
  <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: users/10 in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>27</b><br />
  #with $regex as the key - $routes[$requestType][$regex]
  UsersController@show
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4e3cff4fe18f2d459048f80c47caaae10654595)

Also I imagine the first and second one should work, only the one with the actual regex as the key would be affected due to it's "dynamic" nature.

## Other Stuffs

One thing you are missing is arguments from the url, take the 3rd example (`users/10`) how do you pass that ID (`10`) into your controller? Also, If it was me, I would break the dependency you have on this line `$controller = "App\\Controllers\\{$controller}";` as it limits you to only using classes of the `App\\Controllers\...` namespace.

So to fix that change your data structure to remove that `@` sign.  So instead of this:

```
 $router->get('users', 'UsersController@index');
```

Do it this way:

```
 #Obj::class returns the fully qualified class name (includes namespace)
 # PHP 5.6+ I think?
 $router->get('users', [UsersController::class,'index']);
```

Which will actually simplify your code and give you the possibility of doing things like this (simpler and more flexible):

```
   $router->get('users', function(){
        //do something simple
   });
   #or
   $router->get('users', 'somefunction');
   #or (drop in plugins outside of your normal controller folder)
   $router->get('users', 'Plugins/Users/Controllers/User);
```

So we have to make this slight modifications:

```
public function direct($uri, $requestType)
{
    $matches = [];

    foreach ($this->routes[$requestType] as $regex => $controller) {

        $pattern = "@^" . preg_replace('/\\\:[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+/', '([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)', preg_quote($regex)) . "$@D";

        if ( preg_match($pattern, $uri, $matches ) ) {
            //Simplify the code here and also pass the uri as an array
            return $this->callAction($controller, explode('/', $uri));
        }
    }

    throw new Exception('No route defined for this URI.');
}

protected function callAction($controller, array $args=[])
{
    //you can check types here but all callables work with call_user_func & call_user_func_array

    //you may be able to just check !is_callable($controller) for them all if you don't need the granularity

    if(is_array($controller)){
        //[object, method]
        //[class name, method]
         if(!class_exists($controller[0]) || !method_exists($controller[0], $controller[1])){ 
            //the router has a direct interface to the end user
            //because of this it must handle requests to bad URLs and such
            //direct to 404 page, for example something like this
            //you can and should "log" the errors, but don't show them
            // ---- return $this->error404();
         }  
    }else if(is_object($controller) && !is_callable($controller)){
         //closure or magic method __invoke
          // ---- return $this->error404();
    }else if( !function_exists($controller) ){
         //standard functions
          // ---- return $this->error404();
    }

    return call_user_func_array($action, $args);
}
```

With this simple setup all the args are passed including the name of the controller if it's part of the url.  For exampl, using the third route with a value of this `users/10` would call

```
  $UsersController->show('users', '10');
```

It may prove challenging to remove that without baking the "method" into route path:  For example

```
  $router->get('users/about', 'UsersController@test');
```

There is no way to "know" if "users" is important to the "test" method.  Now if they matched:

```
  $router->get('test/about', 'UsersController@test');
```

You could remove it.  Typically I have seen this pattern in urls

```
   www.yoursite.com/controller/method/...args
```

Which gives us a sort of "grantee" as to what the parts are. But it's your code, you may just decide you can discard the first one no matter what...

I should mention I didn't test any of the above code, but based on my experiance these are features you will probably want at some point.

Cheers!

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix thanks, damn I was so close, I will look into how I can improve this routing with the information you gave me, seems a little bit too complicated right now for my current skill level!
Thanks agian!